# content_scripts not loading for *.google.com sites in my Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to work on a Chrome extension that matches calendar.google.com but the extension never executes the content scripts.

The extension loads into chrome as an unpacked extension, the background and options screens work, but the "meat" of the extension in content_scripts doesn't execute, and doesn't show up in "Sources > Content Scripts" in the dev tools.

Below, I've created the simplest case for a test (using boiler-plate code form the getting started website) and even in this simple case it is reproduced:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
            "js": ["js/test.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**js/test.js**

```
console.log("Extension loaded");
```

I've loaded it unpacked and browsed to a number of different sites to test, and so far, all the *.google.com sites I test do not execute the content_scripts, while any other site seems to execute it (as expected by the "matches" directive of "*://*/*")

Is this a known issue?  I can't find it documented anywhere.  The original extension in the Chrome Web Store that I am actually trying to troubleshoot works for calendar.google.com and so I'm not sure why my unpacked extension testing is not working.

and before commenting about being packed or unpacked, I've even tried packing it and loading it manually but no luck - perhaps it needs to come from the web store to be "trusted" with google.com sites now?

Comment: Most likely your domain admin disabled these URLs via `runtime_blocked_hosts` policy.

Comment: nailed it.  there is a policy for runtime_blocked_hosts under the ExtensionSettings  policy in chrome://policy.  it includes *://*.google.com.   The question is: will the extension work if provided from the web store then (ie: is it no longer considered a "runtime" script)?

Comment: "Runtime" doesn't mean anything here, it refers to some internal component structure in the browser source.